# How can I transform this object into a specific format nicely?

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have a `List<List<JsonCategoryInfo>>` that is grouped by user_id.

```
public class JSONCategoryInfo
{
    public int user_id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
    public int category_id {get; set;}
    public string category {get; set;}
    public int info_id {get; set;}
    public string info_key{get; set;}
    public string info_value{get; set;}
}
```

I am trying to transform it into `List<List<JSONFullChildInfo>>`

```
public class JSONFullChildInfo
{
    public JSONFullChildInfo()
    {
        categoriesAndInfo = new List<CategoriesAndInfo>();
    }
    public int user_id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
    public IList<CategoriesAndInfo> categoriesAndInfo {get; set;} 
}

public class CategoriesAndInfo
{
    public CategoriesAndInfo()
    {
        info = new List<JSONChildInfo>();
    }
    public string category {get; set;}
    public int category_id {get; set;}
    public IList<JSONChildInfo> info {get; set;}
}

public class JSONChildInfo
{
    public int info_id {get; set;}
    public string info_key{get; set;}
    public string info_value{get; set;}
}
```

The only way I was able to do this was with lots of nested loops and lots of probably unnecessary lines of coding. Was wondering if there is an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask]. As it is now, your question is too broad to be a good fit here. Also, we need to see what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

I hope my understanding of your question is correct. Hope following help you.

```
var result = listOfList.SelectMany(x=>x).GroupBy(x=>new {x.user_id,x.name}).Select(jfci=>new JSONFullChildInfo
{
    user_id = jfci.Key.user_id,
    name = jfci.Key.name,
    categoriesAndInfo = jfci.ToList().Select(ci=>new CategoriesAndInfo
    {
        category_id= ci.category_id,
        category = ci.category,
        info = jfci.ToList().Select(jci=>new JSONChildInfo
        {
            info_id = jci.info_id,
            info_key = jci.info_key,
            info_value = jci.info_value
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList(),
});;
```

**Example Input**

[image]

**Example Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I had to adapt it slightly to fully answer my question but the guidance was really helpful!

Comment: @anu how dis you get this graphical view?

Comment: @Sumitraj That's from LinqPad

Answer (score 0):

Answer reached with guidance from @Anu

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Formats triple join into IEnumerable<JSONFullChildInfo>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="allCategoryInfo"> List of all categoies/info of particular user(s)</param>
        /// <returns>Formatted json ready output</returns>
        private IEnumerable<JSONFullChildInfo> formatReadOutput(IEnumerable<JSONCategoryInfo> allCategoryInfo)
        {
            return allCategoryInfo
            .GroupBy(cci => new {
                cci.user_id, 
                cci.name
            }) //Groups by user
            .Select(jfci=>new JSONFullChildInfo //Begin formatting
            {
                user_id = jfci.Key.user_id,
                name = jfci.Key.name,
                categoriesAndInfo = jfci
                .Select(ci=>new CategoriesAndInfo
                {
                    category_id= ci.category_id,
                    category = ci.category,
                    info = jfci
                    .Where(ck => ci.category_id == ck.category_id). //Only grab by correct category id
                    Select(jci=>new JSONChildInfo
                    {
                        info_id = jci.info_id,
                        info_key = jci.info_key,
                        info_value = jci.info_value
                    })
                })
                .GroupBy(r => r.category_id) // This and next line gets rid of duplicates
                .Select(g => g.First())
            });
        }
```